# how is a *= operator calculated inside of a single line algorithm in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, operators

I'm trying to convert some algorithms to another language and am stuck on a few lines of code. The language I'm converting from is actionscript and converting it to lua.

I came across this line

```
return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b
```

is this the same as

```
s = s*1.525
return c/2*(t*t*((s+1)*t - s)) + b
```

or is it the same as

```
newS = s*1.525
return c/2*(t*t*((newS+1)*t - s)) + b
```

so once the *= is called, is s changed throughout the function, so every instance of s is the new value or is it only calculated once and s retains it's value from before?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operators are evaluated from right to left on the same level of nesting. As your original statement has `s*=1.25` enclosed into parentheses the `*=` assignment is executed in advance of addition of `1`, multiplication by `t`, e.t.c., So, your first variant is the correct one.